# htaccess redirect page from subdomain to main domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, drupal, url-rewriting

I have a problem redirecting a page with htaccess.

I've got a page like http://sub.example.com/mycontent
And I want to redirect it to http://www.example.com/mycontent

I've tried to make a simple :

```
RewriteRule http://sub.example.com/en/my-article http://www.example.com/en/my-article [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't seems to work at all.

Do I did something wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't match host name in `RewriteRule`.

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of sub domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?sub\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/my-article http://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that's almost what I wanted, I just need it to be specific to one page only. All other pages are redirect to another place.

Comment: oh check updated rule. Make sure this rule is placed before other rules.